# Check a string in the database to see if it contains an item in an array

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, arrays

What is the best way to do this?  I have this code now, but it is not functional.

```
 if (db.tblOrganizations.Where(x => (
             new string[7] { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "SG" }
         ).Contains(x.strAcronym.ToUpper().Trim()))
     .Select(x => x.guidOrgId)
     .Where(x => x == guidCustOffice)
     .Any())
```

really what I need to do is check to see if the acronym from the database contains any of the string array, that way if the acronym is A1O then it will still fall into the category due to the A1 item in the string[].

Comment: Can you tell us what the field from the database will look like? Is it a variable length field that contains other characters, besides the ones that make up the acronym? Or is the field JUST the acronym by itself?

Comment: @Graham the Acronym field is just a string that varies in length.  In this case it would be 3 digits (A1O, A3R, A5F, etc.) so I would need to check if the aconym from the db contains its parent(A1, A3, A5, etc) to see which commands need to be executed.

Comment: Are the parent acronyms always 2 characters? Is the pattern you are showing always consistent for the parent acronyms? (ie, 1 Letter + 1 Number). If they are wildly inconsistent, then I suspect you'll have to compare the single acronym char by char against all the parent acronyms and find the one that matches "best".

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Sql Server 2008, another option you could explore is [Table Valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510472.aspx)

The following sample (adapted example from [Plamen Ratchev](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2008/04/table-valued-parameters.html)) shows how you could use Table valued params in Sql server

You could use the following in the database:

```
-- User-defined table type
CREATE TYPE LookupCodeTable
AS TABLE (
 lookupcode varchar(10)
)
GO     

-- Procedure with table valued parameter
-- Must use the READONLY clause
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectLoansByCodes
  @lookupCodes LookupCodeTable READONLY
AS
  Select * from Loans 
  inner join @lookupCodes l on Loans.loancode like l.lookupcode + '%'

GO
```

This is sample usage from sql server

```
-- Sample usage from Sql Server
CREATE TABLE Loans (
 loan_nbr INT PRIMARY KEY,
 loancode varchar(50),
 loan_amount DECIMAL(15, 2));


-- Initialize the table variable with data
INSERT INTO Loans
VALUES (1, 'A120080101', 10000.00),
       (2, 'A120080203', 15000.00),
       (3, 'A220080315', 25000.00),
       (4, 'A120080101', 30000.00),
       (5, 'A320080203', 45000.00),
       (6, 'A520080315', 55000.00);

GO 


DECLARE @myLookupcodes LookupCodeTable;

-- Initialize the table variable with data
INSERT INTO @myLookupcodes
VALUES ('A1'), ('A2'), ('A5')

EXEC SelectLoansByCodes @lookupCodes = @myLookupCodes;
```

And sample usage from your application:

```
var loans = new DataTable();
loans.Columns.Add("lookupcode", typeof(string), 10);
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectLoansByCodes", conn)
{
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Loans", loans);
      SqlDataReader reader =
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]));
    }
}
```

and a pointer on using table valued parameters (with functions) with Entity framework:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/07/model-defined-functions.aspx

Answer (score -2):

**

### BAH, not working. Ignore.

**

OK here's my answer. What I am doing here is determining how many characters to compare based on the longest sized acronym in your acronym list. So using your example, I am checking the first two chars of the database result, because the max sized acronym is two chars long.

```
var acronymList = new List<String> { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "SG", };
var dbResult = "A10"; // get this from your database call.

var charsToCheck = acronymList.Max(x => x.Length);

if (charsToCheck > dbResult.Length)
     charsToCheck = dbResult.Length;

var trimmedDbResult = dbResult.Substring(0, charsToCheck);

var foundAcronym = acronymList.SingleOrDefault(acronym => acronym == trimmedDbResult);

if (foundAcronym != null)
{
     // use the found acronym
     Response.Write(foundAcronym); // prints "A1" in this example.
}

else
{
     // acronym not found, handle error
     Response.Write("error");
}
```

Comment: I think the point is to this using LINQ-to-SQL, so that the query is executed on the database. What's more, your code wouldn't work if some of items in `acronymList` had different length.

Comment: The variables "acronymList" and "dbResult" come from L2S database queries. I expressed them as simple variables here for the sake of brevity.

Comment: And my code works just fine with different lengths of the items in acronymList, although I have just added an IF statement to make sure the length that I'm using in the Substring call isn't greater than the length of the dbResult string itself.

Comment: Not sure it would work... In your example above if the acronym list has BOB in it then trimmedDbResult would be "A10" which wouldn't match anything in the list. Assuming that my in-head runtime is working properly anyway...